# Retrieving unique list of data given that previous values is not the same in Excel 365/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-365

I want to, given a set dataset as shown (with generic names) below, either using VBA or excel functions, find each unique row in the table and putting them into another sheet.

The issue comes when I have several items for the same value, but name/item differs.

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| Value |  Name   |  Item  |
+-------+---------+--------+
|     1 | Name 11 | Item 4 |
|     1 | Name 12 | Item 2 |
|     2 | Name 7  | Item 3 |
|     2 | Name 10 | Item 3 |
|     2 | Name 10 | Item 1 |
|     3 | Name 9  | Item 1 |
|     3 | Name 1  | Item 2 |
|     4 | Name 13 | Item 3 |
|     5 | Name 8  | Item 4 |
|     5 | Name 12 | Item 1 |
|     5 | Name 4  | Item 2 |
|     6 | Name 9  | Item 2 |
|     7 | Name 14 | Item 3 |
|     8 | Name 7  | Item 1 |
|     9 | Name 1  | Item 2 |
|     9 | Name 6  | Item 1 |
|     9 | Name 15 | Item 1 |
|     9 | Name 3  | Item 4 |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

I've tried using `=UNIQUE()` in excel, but to no help. `=XLOOKUP()` is another function I've tried using, but it only retrieves the item for the first value, not the items with different names or values.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to create a VBA code, or solve this using Excel-functions?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Every single row in your example is unique.

Comment: It would help if you show us the desired output

Comment: Each row in your data right now is unique. Anyways, Pivot Tables is what you need